# C++ enable_if in class - different ways of destruction

Tags: c++, templates, destructor

I am developing an application for an embedded device and therefore I do not have `type_traits` and `enable_if` (poor compiler quality). I created them on my own:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_t{
    enum{value = false};
};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_t<T*>{
    enum{value = true};
};
```

and simillar declarations for `consts` and `volatiles`.

Now implementation of `enable_if`:

```
template <bool boolean, typename T = void>
struct enable_if{};

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>{
    typedef T type;
};
```

Now I want to have a class, that depeneding on wheather I use pointers or normal types it calls destructor on them or not, so it would be great if I could have templated destructor. But I do not know how to do this as I am just beginning to undestand template programming. Following attempts failed:

```
template <typename T>
class pointerOrNot{
public:

    template <typename U>
    void one();
};

template <typename T>
template <typename enable_if<is_pointer_t<T>::value>::type>
void pointerOrNot<T>::one(){
    std::cout << "Success1" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename enable_if<!is_pointer_t<T>::value>::type>
void pointerOrNot<T>::one(){
    std::cout << "Success2" << std::endl;
}
```

and it says it does not match definition. So I tried following:

```
template <typename T>
class pointerOrNot{
public:

    template <typename enable_if<is_pointer_t<T>::value>::type>
    void one();
    template <typename enable_if<!is_pointer_t<T>::value>::type>
    void one();
};
```

But then one of one() has empty type as template and compilation fails. How can I do this? Also is it possible to do this with destructor?

Comment: Instead of a choice on destruction policy, I would simply not accept any raw pointers, because of the ownership issue. You can still use raw pointers wrapped in smart pointer objects, which do the destruction or not, as a client code choice. It's not difficult to define a smart pointer, and this is one good way to entirely **separate concerns**.

Comment: If you really do want a choice on pointer type versus non-pointer then you can use a helper function template, specialized for is and is-not. You could also use a so called "policy based design", which essentially is about having a template P as template parameter, where P is instantiated by e.g. your T and provides e.g. destruction operation. But you get a much simpler and more clean separation of concerns with smart pointers.

Comment: For a In My Humble Opinion much more readable alternative to `enable_if`, that I call just `If_`, see (https://github.com/alf-p-steinbach/cppx/blob/plutonium/core_language_support/tmp/If_.hpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets consider the following class for pointers:

```
template <typename T>
struct Introducer{

  void intro(){
    std::cout<<"I'm a pointer, I point to adress "<<mem<<std::endl;
  }

  T mem;
  Introducer(T m):mem(m){}
};
```

it works fine with pointers, but it also works with non-pointers:

```
  Introducer<int> i(10);
  i.intro();//just fine!
```

We would like to detect this misuse during the compile time, also we change Introducer to

```
template <typename T>
struct Introducer{

  typename enable_if<is_pointer_t<T>::value, void>::type //this is the return type of the function
  intro(){
    std::cout<<"I'm a pointer, I point to adress "<<mem<<std::endl;
  }

  ...
};
```

Now compiler does not allow us to use non-pointer with Introducer. In the next step we would like to have a special function for non-pointers by means of [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error):

```
template <typename T>
struct Introducer{
  typename enable_if<is_pointer_t<T>::value, void>::type 
  intro(){
    std::cout<<"I'm a pointer, I point to adress "<<mem<<std::endl;
  }

  typename enable_if<!is_pointer_t<T>::value, void>::type 
  intro(){
    std::cout<<"I'm a non-pointer, my value is "<<mem<<std::endl;
  }

  ...
};
```

Hell, it does not even compile! Lets read the passage about SFINAE more carefully:

> If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type
>   deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be
>   ill-formed if written using the substituted arguments. Only invalid
>   types and expressions **in the immediate context** of the function type
>   and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure.

`T` is not in the immediate context and thus SFINAE doesn't work, lets bring `T` into the immediate context:

```
template <typename T>
struct Introducer{

  template <typename C=T>
  typename enable_if<is_pointer_t<C>::value, void>::type 
  intro(){
    std::cout<<"I'm a pointer, I point to adress "<<mem<<std::endl;
  }


  template <typename C=T>
  typename enable_if<!is_pointer_t<C>::value, void>::type 
  intro(){
    std::cout<<"I'm a non-pointer, my value is "<<mem<<std::endl;
  }

  ...
};
```

now the program

```
int main(){
  Introducer<float*> fp(NULL);
  fp.intro();

  //But this works also:
  Introducer<int> i(10);
  i.intro();
}
```

results in:

```
I'm a pointer, I point to adress 0
I'm a non-pointer, my value is 10
```

What about the destructor? The easiest way would be to call a SFINAE-destruction-function from the destructor (I never saw a SFINAE-destructor and would not know how to write one, but this doesn't mean anything):

```
template <typename T>
struct Introducer{
  ...

    ~Introducer(){
    intro();
    std::cout<<"and I'm deleted..."<<std::endl;
  }
};
```